# get and getList why no have the same unit?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

In my application I'm having the bellow problem

**SERVER RESPONSE DATA**

**route /users**

```
{ data: [
    { id: 5, name: 'peter' },
    { id: 10, name: 'adan' }
] }
```

**route /users/5**

```
{ data: { id: 5, name: 'peter' } }
```

**case01**

```
Restangular.one('users', 5).get().then(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
});
```

**case02**

```
Restangular.all('users').getList().then(function(users){
    $scope.user = users[0];
});
```

- In my case02 I can access $scope.user.id, but in case01 I have that to do $scope.user.data.id (what's not preferible when I render this in my template with {{ user.id }} where I have that use {{ user.data.id }} )
- In my case02 I can change my data and use $scope.user.save(), but in my case01 I can't access this function

In my restangular I configure this for handle data from server when I use getList because it come in one object and not in one Array

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseInterceptor(function(response, operation, what) {
    if (operation === "getList") {
        // from:
        // {data: [{ id: 1, name: 'peter' }, { id: 2, name: 'adan' }]}
        // to:
        // [{ id: 1, name: 'peter' }, { id: 2, name: 'adan' }]
        return response.data;
    }
    return response;
});
```

---

So I would not work, because then I will have a normal JS object and not a Restangular object, the Restangular object has several methods that I still intend to use the same $scope, so we would like to preserve this.

example:
In an item from a case02 consultation (array) I have an object with methods of Restangular:
all (), allUrl (), one (), oneUrl (), ... and the properties of the object I sought (id, name) within $ scope.user.

```
{
    all: function(){...}, 
    allUrl: function(){...}, 
    one: function(){...},
    oneUrl: function(){...},
    ...
    id: data_from_user,
    name: data_from_user
}
```

In an item from a case01 query (object) I have an object with methods of Restangular within $ scope.user and object properties that sought (id, name) within $ scope.user.data.

```
{
    all: function(){...}, 
    allUrl: function(){...}, 
    one: function(){...},
    oneUrl: function(){...},
    ...
    data: {
        id: data_from_user,
        name: data_from_user
    }
}
```

For this reason it would not work the solution you presented because it is okay to work with restangular the subject, not an object of normal JS, but thank you for the answer Tim Castelijns.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (operation === "getList") {
    // from:
    // {data: [{ id: 1, name: 'peter' }, { id: 2, name: 'adan' }]}
    // to:
    // [{ id: 1, name: 'peter' }, { id: 2, name: 'adan' }]
    return response.data;
}
return response;
```

If operation is getList, you return `response.data`, which is

```
[
    { id: 5, name: 'peter' },
    { id: 10, name: 'adan' }
]
```

but if operation is **not** getList, you return `response`, which is the entire object, including the *data* sub-object

```
{ 
    data: { 
        id: 5,
        name: 'peter' 
    } 
}
```

Your choice to return different results depending on what operation it is, is the reason you need to do `user.data.id` for case01, because you assign the result to `user` with `then(function(user)`, when in fact `user` represents the entire data sub-object containing the user.

You should be able to solve it by changing to this

```
Restangular.one('users', 5).get().then(function(response){
    $scope.user = response['data'];
});
```

Comment: I edit my question and add details that show because I can't use your idea.